# Changing Xaml Slider value with RenderTransform

Tags: windows, xaml, user-interface, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm making a Metro Xaml control based off of a couple of sliders. Essentially, on the ManipulationDelta event -- specifically, a translation along the X axis -- of one of the slider thumbs, I would like to translate another slider thumb by the same amount. The issue I run into is that using RenderTransform to translate the other thumb doesn't change the value of its slider, but rather superficially changes the thumb position.

Is there an easier solution to getting the value of the slider to match the thumb position than just projecting the thumb position into the slider value using a couple calculations?

EDIT: 
This is a more careful and thorough explanation of what I am trying to do:

Essentially, I am trying to make a UI control that represents a preview window -- a stretchable, translatable (along the X axis) bar that allows you to select some portion of the corresponding video you'd like to preview.

Behind the scenes, I use two sliders to represent the left and right thumbs of the preview window, and a rectangle that connects the two slider thumbs that allows you translate the rectangle and the two thumbs in tandem. The thumbs of the two sliders allow you to stretch the window.

The stretching is done by increasing the width of the rectangle. The translation via the rectangle is done by using TranslateTransform objects.

Answer (score 1):

The regular [Slider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.slider.aspx) control does not require handling any manipulations or applying render transforms. You can just bind a value of one slider to the value of the other one and they will move in tandem.

```
<StackPanel
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Slider
        Width="300"
        Minimum="0"
        Maximum="10"
        StepFrequency="0.1"
        Value="{Binding Value, ElementName=slider2, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <Slider
        x:Name="slider2"
        Width="300"
        Minimum="0"
        Maximum="10"
        StepFrequency="0.1" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: The only problem is that the bound Slider is already involved in another data binding. In your example, the first slider would be bound to a MediaElement. Otherwise, how would I achieve the same effect except using a Rectangle object?

Comment: If there are hidden preconditions - you should share more details about these. You can use events instead of bindings, or you can set up bindings elsewhere so the whole setup becomes possible. I am just convinced that using manipulations or transforms with sliders must be wrong.

Comment: @Zach, [this question on MSDN](http://alturl.com/eo6ns) suggests that WinRT doesn't support the MultiBinding to this day. Nonetheless you can use [*BindingListener class available at prism framework WP7*](http://alturl.com/6vu7o). You can check the [sample project](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=a179313882495dc1&resid=A179313882495DC1!232&id=A179313882495DC1!232) by the OP of MSDN question (which he implemented with [some help](http://alturl.com/vpxwo)). Hope it solves your problem. 8

Comment: Bindings can be chained. For example:

Comment: Bindings can be chained. Example:

MediaElement.Progress <-- Slider1.Value <-- Slider2.Value

The mode of each binding can be OneWay or TwoWay. In other words, Slider1 could impact Slider2 but potentially not the other way around.

Even more importantly, Slider1 and Slider2 could both be bound to the MediaElement. Then, when you slide either one of the sliders the MediaElement would update and - as a result - the other slider would snap to the same value. Of course in this case the update would happen after the change and not during the slide.

RenderTransform only affects draw, not values.